# irsend: how to overcome the "transmission failed" error

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, lirc

Does anyone have experience in configuring LIRC for IR blasting? I've been all over the web for a couple of days now trying to figure out how to configure my Ubuntu Server to send out an IR signal from the back of my TV Tuner card to change the channel on my set top box. I have MythTV set up on the server, but it lacks the ability to change channels on the set top box, which I why I need LIRC. However, I keep hitting a wall just trying to get the program(LIRC) to transmit:

```
[15:00]<~>$ sudo irsend send_once DCT2000 POWER
irsend: command failed: send_once DCT2000 POWER
irsend: transmission failed
```

I'm pretty sure all my config files are correct, otherwise I'd be getting socket errors. Of all the guides I've run into, they mostly seem to be Raspberry Pi specific and have custom built IR receivers and transmitters. [This](https://www.piddlerintheroot.com/ir-blaster-lirc/) has been the most helpful guide, but I dunno how to translate the pin setup into something non-Pi specific. I'm not quite sure if this is a software or hardware problem, but any guidance would be much appreciative.

**How do I overcome this transmission error?**

The server runs Ubuntu Server 16.04, and has a "Hauppauge 1199 WinTV HVR-1600 Internal PCI Dual TV Tuner/Video Recorder with IR Receiver and Blaster" tuner card in it. The tuner card has a little 2.5mm jack for an IR transmitter.